# How to to observe onto reyclerview changes in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a list with data from data base. I am a beginner in android and now I have difficulties. I don't know how can I to observe onto reyclerview changes and then change my list.  for example I have list with 50 items.  data for any item is changed and I need change it in the list. In real time. Tell me please how can I do it? I don't use any pattern , ViewModel, LiveData.

Comment: `how can I to observe onto reyclerview` you don't, you never observe onto a recyclerview. recyclerviews are managed by adapters. specifically, adapters with data. observe onto the data

Comment: But how can I observe onto the data ?

Answer (score 1):

A RecyclerView has an `Adapter` that manages the data, you pass the data to the adapter with something like this at a very basic level

```
myAdapter.myAdapterData = myNewData
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

notifyDataSetChanged causes the adapter to update the data in the RecyclerView.

That being said you typically dont want to use notifyDataSetChanged as that causes everything in the recyclerview to be redone. You would use something like notifyItemChanged or the many other method calls that deals with only things that changed and not the whole dataset.

There are some other ways too but just starting off learning you should do that first

Comment: ListAdapter may be easier for beginners because it automatically finds the differences and updates specific rows as needed.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yeah I was debating on if I wanted to mention that because then you also have to learn about DiffUtil too and using it you dont get an understanding of what is happening since its doing it for you

Comment: @Tenfour04, yes, I read about DiffUtil. But when for example I call in fragment method for list update I don't understand what I have to pass as a parameter (newList)

Comment: @tyczj, But if I will use adapter methods  I need to  know element position . For example I have list ,which every time changes. And I can't track every element,  what position does it have every time.

Comment: @Monica Thats correct, you would have to get the items the adapter currently has and find the index in there. that is what DiffUtil is basically doing behind the scenes